# Can I initialize a reference from the value of dereferencing the return of `new`?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

As I've seen, `new` allocates an un-named object in the free store and returns a pointer to that un-named object.

So we can create a reference to that object:

```
int* pi = new int(100);
int& ri = *pi;
```

What interests me is I can create an object on the free store without assigning the return of `new` to a pointer, but to a reference to the un-named object through assigning the de-referenced value of `new` to the reference:

```
int& x = *(new int(7));

cout << x << endl; // 7
x += 34;
cout << x << endl; // 41
```

I want to know whether I can do this, or is it a bad idea?

N.B: In production, I keep away as much as possible from handling raw memory, I use smart pointers and STL containers instead.

Comment: Yes. But now you need to ask is `delete &ri;` valid?

Comment: How could you delete that memory? `delete &x;` which is more error-prone and less readable, And after thousands of lines you are stuck.

Comment: @RichardCritten It is.  `delete` requires *a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression* which `&ri` gives you.

Comment: @NathanOliver `&ri` is a pointer but is it the same as the pointer returned by the original new expression? Does the standard guarantee `pi == &ri`

Comment: @RichardCritten It doesn't need to be.  It needs *a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression*.  I believe we can both agree that if `ri` refers to the object returned by the new expression then `&ri` is a pointer to the object returned by the new expression.

Comment: @RichardCritten And yes, it has to since `ri` is formed from `*pi`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know whether I can do this or it is a bad idea?

You can do this, but you really shouldn't.  The reason is that it makes it harder to remember to deallocate the memory you received since you are no longer using a pointer. That gets you out of the pointer frame of mind and makes it easier to forget to have a call to `delete` on all exit paths.

It is also going to look weird when you deallocate because you'd need to do something like

```
delete &x;
```

Comment: Thank you as usual! with very informative and helpful answers! Do you know I always try anything before reading it from a book or ask it here to enlarge my imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But I would consider it a bad idea. Once this reference goes out of scope, you have no way of freeing the dynamic memory,  (or you simply forget, that it's dynamic memory in disguise) which will most likely cause a memory leak.

Comment: Pointers also go out of scope.